# Open Internet Explorer in InPrivate browsing mode through robotframework

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, robotframework

I am trying to open IE in InPrivate mode through RobotFramework as below:

```
${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER  sys, selenium.webdriver
Log To Console ${dc}
Set To Dictionary  ${dc}    ie.forceCreateProcessApi=${True}    ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=-private
Log To Console ${dc}
Open Browser    www.google.com   ie  desired_capabilitie=${dc}
```

The script is stuck at the last step until pressing Ctrl+C. Does anybody know how to solve the issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found the issue on my system. The problem happens when I use IEDriverServer 32 bit on my Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections    
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test IE InPrivate
    ${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ignoreProtectedModeSettings    ${True}
    Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ie.forceCreateProcessApi       ${True}
    Set To Dictionary   ${dc}   ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=-private
    Open Browser    www.google.com  ie  desired_capabilitie=${dc}
```

However, do be aware that in order for the `forceCreateProcessApi` setting to work an additional Registry key needs to be added: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth = '0'`. Otherwise the following error is presented:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Unable to use 
CreateProcess() API. To use CreateProcess() with Internet Explorer 8 or higher, the value 
of registry setting in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth must be '0'.
```

Comment: Can you mark this answer then as the answer so that other who have a similar issue recognize it more easily?